# phpMyAdmin import issue

Tags: phpmyadmin, redhat

I have a file of size **8.44M** which I'm trying to import into a database via PHPMyAdmin.

However, I keep getting the following message:

> Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

When I following the messages' instructions and resubmit the file, it complains about conflicting table names.

In php.ini I have the following data settings:

```
memory_limit           512M
post_max_size           10M
upload_max_filesize     10M
```

This all seems fine to me.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: restart apache server once....

Answer (score 0):

I got this from a website:

in the phpmyadmin config.inc.php you can increase the time out from 300sec to infinity

add this line

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

Source:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,88840,88845